# VIM 'dot' command not working

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using MacVim as my primary code editor but cannot seem to figure out a small issue I'm having. I am unable to use the period key to repeat last command. Instead, it simply deletes the selected line. I have Janus installed but I don't think that is affecting things. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all commands are considered for repetition by `.`, for example cursor movement commands are not considered. The `.` command will repeat the last command that *was* considered, which might have been `dd` in your case (which deletes a line).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that was the case.

Comment: @Julian25: See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_04.html#04.3 for more information on what `.` does.

Comment: @Julian25, also consider taking a look at [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat)- it enables the dot command to repeat plugin motions (as opposed to only repeating the last native command).